# How to let nested function run in parallel using OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Take the following code as an example:

```
void func(void) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}

int main(void) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want `main` function spawns `2` `func` thread, and in every `func` thread, it will generate another `3` threads. So there will be `8` threads totally. But run the above program:

```
$ ./a.out
main: 1
main: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
func: 0
```

It indicates that only the outer `2` threads are created. I try to use `collapse`:

```
void func(void) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}

int main(void) {
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following complaints:

```
parallel.c: In function ‘main’:
parallel.c:15:3: error: not enough perfectly nested loops before ‘printf’
   printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
   ^~~~~~
```

So the `collapse` should only work in following scenario:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }
```

Is there any method to let nested function run in parallel?